# How can I move a module inside a subdirectory?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I need to write a lot of *trivial* modules and I don't want to hide the main modules between them. For this reason I want to have a directory tree like this:

```
Project
|-module1
|-module2
+-directory
    |-module3
    |-module4
    +-module5
```

The problem: if I move the modules inside a new folder Android Studio doesn't find them.

So, my question is: How can I move modules inside a directory?

Comment: Is this for creating a new project? Or modifying an existing one?

Comment: Create new modules in a existing project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would recommend closing the project in Android Studio, moving the directories manually in your OS, and updating the project's **settings.gradle** file to point to the modules in their new location. Using your example, the updated **settings.gradle** file will look like this:

```
include ':module1'
include ':module2'
include ':directory:module3'
include ':directory:module4'
include ':directory:module5'
```

Then re-open the project in Android Studio, and make sure it syncs the project with the new Gradle files (which it should do automatically, but if it doesn't, click the toolbar button for it).

Comment: Refactor -> Move does the trick. Then make changes to the settings.gradle as mentioned here.

Answer (score 5):

You can now define the location of modules with

```
include ':myModule'    

project(':myModule').projectDir = new File('dir/myModule')
```

Further, you have to remove the **.iml** files under the module directory to let Android Studio recreate them.

Comment: Doing include ':directory:moduleX' didn't work for me, this is the only solution that worked

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add them as a new module.

1. Open the new module dialog either via:

   - *File > New Module*; or
   - *File > Project Structure, [Modules]* and click the add icon [image] and select *New Module*
2. Select the module type, I assuming `Android` in your case. Then select the Android module type
3. Click Next
4. Either type in or use the browse button [image] to open the file chooser and enter the "Content Root" as `Project\directory\module3`
5. The "module file location" should update to match the content root, but double check it and set it if necessary
6. Click Finish
7. Repeat for the other modules

By default, in the project tool window tree, it will show a flat structure of:

```
Project
+-Module1
+-Module2    
+-Module3
+-Module4
+-Module5
```

If you want to add a hierarchy to the project tree structure:

1. Open the project structure dialog (File > Project Structure)
2. Select the `modules` panel on the left.
3. Select module3 and right click it. Select *Move Module to Group > New Top Level Group*.
4. Enter a name and click OK.
5. for all the other sub modules, select them, right click, and select *Move Module to Group > {yourGroupName} > To this group*

Now in the project tool window, those modules will be grouped into a hierarchy.

Comment: This options are not at Android Studio. I suppose that this options are at IntelliJ Idea... I probably need to change to *pure* IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant where you include modules and provide their paths

```
include ':module1', ':module2', ':module3'

project(':module1').projectDir = new File('modules/module1')
project(':module2').projectDir = new File('modules/module2')
project(':module3').projectDir = new File('modules/module3')
```