# Android Studio - How to make modules inside a subdirectory?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Suppose that I had 3 modules: mod1, mod2 and mod3.

In normal case, the file system hierarchy should be:

```
[android_root_dir]
build.gradle # list this file just to make it clear.
----mod1
----mod2
----mod3
```

But what I want is:

```
[android_root_dir]
build.gradle # list this file just to make it clear.
----modules
    ----mod1
    ----mod2
    ----mod3
```

how to do it in Android Studio 1.1.0?

PS: I find this article but it does not seem to work, or it works for earlier versions of AS, not 1.1.0:
[How can I move a module inside a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904930/how-can-i-move-a-module-inside-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can do it:

```
root
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  modules
    mod1
      build.gradle
    mod2
      build.gradle
    mod3
      build.gradle
```

In your `settings.gradle`

```
include ':modules:mod1' , ':modules:mod2', ':modules:mod3'
```

Comment: thx for your feedback. this method works...somewhat... AS will generate a fake and null module with the name of "modules", and generate "modules/modules.iml". if i delete this module in AS project structure, AS will auto-generate it again. any ideas?

Comment: i give it up for hours of research on this topic... what's important is the project itself... i use this means now: name modules with name prefix of "module", such as moduleMain, moduleFuncA, moduleFuncB, etc...

Comment: @McArthorLee If you do not want to see the null module, you can choose "Load/Unload modules ..." from the menu and unload the null module.

Answer (score 13):

**Android Module inside a subdirectory**

`settings.gradle` file

```
include ':module1', ':module2', ':module3'

project(':module1').projectDir = new File('modules/module1')
project(':module2').projectDir = new File('modules/module2')
project(':module3').projectDir = new File('modules/module3')
```

[[Example]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802250/4770877)

Answer (score 12):

Though `include ':modules:mod1' , ':modules:mod2', ':modules:mod3'` kind of gives you the solution, the AS annoyingly generates an empty module for `modules`. To address this gotcha, please refer to the `settings.gradle` on the [gradle github repo](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/settings.gradle). It basically includes every subproject as a top level one and then sets its project directory to be inside the subdirectory. This trick should perfectly address your need.

```
include 'mod1'
include 'mod2'
...
include 'modX'
rootProject.name = 'gradle'
rootProject.children.each {project ->
    String projectDirName = "modules/$project.name"
    project.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, projectDirName)
    assert project.projectDir.isDirectory()
    assert project.buildFile.isFile()
}
```

Comment: Same result can be achieved by adding new 'build.gradle' in the intermediate directory 'modules', with content:
`jar.enabled = false;
uploadArchives.enabled = false`

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you want to create a new module 'myfeature' and place it inside the 'features' folder:

1. File -> New -> New Module
2. In the Templates pane choose Android Library
3. In the Module Name write ':features:myfeature'
4. modify the rest of the fields to suit your needs
5. Click on Finish

Now if you didn't have a 'features' folder it will be automatically created and a new module named 'myfeature' will be placed inside it. Otherwise the new module will appear inside the existing 'features' module.

Answer (score 3):

My project struct

```
Coding
   app
   push-dir
     coding-push
     push-xiaomi
   setting.gradle
```

setting.gradle file

```
// need repeat declarative, i think it's bug
include ':app'
include ':coding-push'
include ':push-dir:coding-push'
include ":push-xiaomi"
include ":push-dir:push-xiaomi"
```

I used repeat declarative in settings.gradle to solve. (Android Studio 3.0), I think it's AS's bug.
Sometimes need restart AS.