# Two unmerged repositories inside one project

Tags: android, git, module

I have a project that uses modules. One of the modules that I need to use is inside another repository. In the future, I will connect that module into my project using `mavenCentral`, but not now.

I want to have my MODULE from another repository inside my PROJECT without adding the MODULE into my PROJECT GIT. And I should be able to switch between git repos and commit the changes into their corresponding repositories.

So far I did this:

-- added MODULE origin inside PROJECT like so.

```
git remote add MODULE [module URL in Github]
git fetch MODULE
```

after the above steps, when I do `git remote -v` it is displaying two remotes. One for PROJECT (origin) and one for MODULE.

After these steps, I am not sure what to do next in order to achieve my objective. Is it even possible?

I tried `git merge MODULE/master --allow-unrelated-histories` but it is adding my MODULE code into my PROJECT which I don't want.

Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for that kind of use.

Your parent repository would keep a reference on your MODULE repository in a MODULE subfolder, but any change done on that subfolder can be pushed directly to the remote MODULE repository.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git submodule add [module URL]
cd module
# work on module, add, push, commit
cd ..
git add module
git commit -m "reference new module state"
```

The [OP amira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5842014/amira) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73300599/two-unmerged-repositories-inside-one-project/73301096?noredirect=1#comment129517236_73301096):

> Worked like a charm.
> In the `settings.gradle` folder, don't forget to include the module and provide a path as described in "[Android Studio - How to make modules inside a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28658574/6309)".

Comment: Oh yeah, this is what I am looking for. I will try it out and let you know. Thanks @VonC

Comment: I tried this solution and worked like a charm. In the `settings.gradle` folder don't forget to include the module and provide a path as described in this SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658574/android-studio-how-to-make-modules-inside-a-subdirectory

Comment: @amira Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.