# Create and Move Phone Module into a subdirectory

Tags: android, android-studio, module

## Summary

I am working on extending my Android Library, and in the library I want to have a directory that has the ability to add many different and working sample Android apps in their own modules.

I have already created one sample app that I would like to move and rename I guess; however, I need the ability to add other ones easily.

## Previous Tries

- [How can I move a module inside a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904930/how-can-i-move-a-module-inside-a-subdirectory?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Android Studio - How to make modules inside a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658574/android-studio-how-to-make-modules-inside-a-subdirectory)

These two solutions that allow to create a module exactly how I want structurally; **however, these solutions will only create a standard java module. I specifically need an Android App module.**

Another option that I have tried was to directly use Android Studio's New Module Wizard. **This option allows me to create an Android App Module; however, it will not put it in the correct structure.**

## What I have

```
Project Module
|- Android Library Module
|- "samples" Android App Module (Complex)
```

## What I want

```
Project Module
|- Android Library Module
+- "samples" Directory
   |- "sample-basic" Android App Module
   |- "sample-complex" Android App Module
```

So what am I missing? I have seen other git repos that have Android app modules inside of subdirectories. So it appears to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is correct way to get everything specified above...

## 1. Create Basic Android Module

First use the `Android Studio's New Module Wizard` to create 2 Android Modules; one for the basic sample, and another for the in-depth sample.

## 2. Code

In the `settings.gradle` file, copy the code below.

This will create `3 modules` as direct child modules to the project. Further steps are needed to create the `subdirectory` and put the correct modules in it.

*All of that without creating a module for the subdirectory*.

**Please note:** that the outcome of this are 3 basic java modules. However, the `:accessibility` module was already declared as an `Android Library Module` before. So the real outcome is the creation of 2 additional `Java Modules`.

*This is not quite what I want...but it is very close!*

```
include ':accessibility', ':samples-basic', 'samples-indepth'

// Set the root projects name - the Project Module
rootProject.name = 'accessibility'

// For each module within the project - i.e. "app" module, etc...
rootProject.children.each { project ->

    // Only modify modules that contain the selected word. Note: do whatever logic is needed to sort and move the correct modules
    if (project.name.contains("samples")) {

        // Move the module into a specific subdirectory
        String projectDirName = "samples/$project.name"
        project.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, projectDirName)

        assert project.projectDir.isDirectory()
        assert project.buildFile.isFile()

    }
}
```

## 3. Move the Android Sample Modules

Now that you have all the code finished, just take the 2 Android Sample Modules and move them to the samples subdirectory. Once the move is complete, you are finished

#### Results

```
"Accessibility" Project Module
|- "accessibility" Library Module
+- "samples" Directory
   |- "samples-basic" Android App Module
   |- "samples-complex" Android App Module
```